# When to use tensorflow or api.ai

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I am evaluating the chatbot development technologies. Tensorflow and API.ai are (both from google) the options I am considering right now. But I am not sure which one to choose. Can you provide pointers when Tensorflow is suitable and when to use API.ai?

Answer (score 2):

**API.ai:**

- You can build a running bot in a few minutes.
- User friendly UI.
- Develop a bot with even wright single line of code.
- Verify fast integration with messaging platform like Facebook, telegram,     slack etc..
- It is also good for prototyping bot app.
- Already trained(ready-made) lot of general purpose conversation so that you can use directly.
- Difficult to build complex conversation.

**Tensorflow:**

- Tensorflow is general purpose machine learning/deep learing library.
- Good to build complex conversation.
- Time consume train conversation.

Answer (score 0):

API.ai basically provides an NLP engine which understands NLP and extracts intents entities, etc. for your use. For example, you can simply build a simple chat-bot using this.

On the other hand, tensorflow is a general deep learning/machine learning framework. You can build (almost) any deep learning/ machine learning algorithms using TensorFlow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please tell me the real application/usage of tensor flow (other than chatbots)?